# Хранение файлов приложения в Андроиде

Tags: android

Подскажите, где хранить файлы для своего приложения?

Вижу папку Android/data с названиями программ, но следующий код не создает папку

```
new File("/Android/data/programmname").mkdirs();
```

Где можно создать папку и хранить файлы?

Comment: разрешение добавлено?

Comment: нет, не добавлено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `Context.getFilesDir()` или `Context.getExternalFilesDir()`

[Документация](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: То, что надо!  Подошло.

Answer (score 0):

проверь манифест файл на наличие прав доступа, вот пример как работать с файловой системой http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Какие права доступа нужны? WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE стоит. На карте памяти папки создаются. А в памяти телефона нет.